# Using spans to shape text inside li elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am having some issues shaping text inside li elements. One problem I have is that the float-right divs do not float to the top right but leave a space at the top. Also, the text is not properly 'shaping' correctly. As you can see from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u773M/) jsfiddle, the divs are well inside the grid lines, however the text does appear outside the lines. Also is there a way to put dashes to separate words when they don't fit (like I did on the last one), or make the text smaller?

Updated jsfiddle that shows bad text overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/u773M/1/

Here is my php that creates the text float divs:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
 echo '<div class="trianglefloatleft" style="width:'.(3+($i*6)).'%;"></div>';
 echo '<div class="trianglefloatright" style="width:'.(9+($i*6)).'%;"></div>'; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hakra, I got partly there. However, the real solution is much simpler and makes more sense (don't know why it took me so long to realize this): Put the float right divs first!

Updated code for those that care: http://jsfiddle.net/u773M/4/

Answer (score 1):

if you add this it will work

```
<div class="trianglefloatleft" style="width:9%;"></div>
<div class="trianglefloatright" style="width: 9%; margin-top: -12px;"></div>
```

it mean you are creating the div of width 9% only once according to your condition